# Generic host process problem

Tags: windows-xp

My PC config. is WinXP SP2.
I use my sony ericsson mobile  to surf net on my PC.
After surfing net 5-10 min. my PC display a msg box saying Generic Host Process Problem.
Please suggest me how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894391

Make sure Windows XP has the latest critical updates and restart the computer after doing so.

I'm assuming your Sony Ericsson Mobile is getting it's Internet connection from your Windows XP machine via blue tooth. If so do you just get the **Generic Host Process** error after surfing online on the Sony device?

Comment: Thanks for replying , but now i observed this error comes even when  not connected to the internet but while my mobile is merely connected to the system. By the way i use data cable for this purpose and not via bluetooth

Comment: If it's connected via USB try updating your Chipset drivers and reinstalling any software that Sony may provide.